# How Can I Insert All subject marks for one student at a time ? ? Want It Dynamically bcz Subjects might be change

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

i have Exam_Result table and Subject_Info table like this....

```
1] Exam_Result table....

Resultid         numeric(18, 0)   Unchecked
Enroll_Number    varchar(50)      Checked
Student_Name     varchar(100)     Checked
Course_Id        varchar(50)      Checked
Semester         varchar(50)      Checked
Subject_Id       varchar(50)      Checked
MarksObtained    numeric(18, 0)   Checked
Exam_Type        varchar(50)      Checked

2] Subject_Info table....

Subject_Id       varchar(20)    Unchecked
Subject_Name     varchar(50)    Checked
Semester         varchar(10)    Checked
Course_Id        varchar(20)    Checked
Course_Type      varchar(20)    Checked
```

i want to insert each sub marks at a time....for eg want to enter each sub marks of unique student Enroll_No with 11111, Course_Id = CIV and Sem = 1....

```
Enroll_Number 11111
Course_Id     CIV
Semester      1
```

here's are the subjects...i want to enter marks like this....

```
Subject_Id   MarksObtained
EM           23
SM           25
CL           30
```

And This result must be stored into Exam_Result table....

**NOTE: Subjects are not fix for every semester it might be change as per school... so i want it with dynamic solutions...**

Can you plz help me how i can solve this problem..??? or any other soltuon the give it to me.... thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2005 you can use the INSERT... UNION ALL hack to insert multiple rows in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
```

as described in more detail here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/

As an aside, with SQL Server 2008, inserting multiple rows is supported by TSQL natively:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Name, City, Phone)
VALUES
    ('Customer #1', 'Jerusalem', '2343245'),
    ('Customer #2', 'Tel Aviv', '0987345'),
    ('Customer #3', 'Haifa', '275466')
```

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/12/05/sql-server-2008-t-sql-insert-multiple-rows.aspx

**EDIT:**

As requested, to build such a string in C#, you could do something like the following:

```
// create some dummy data
var data = new List<Tuple<string, int>>
{
    new Tuple<string, int>("First", 1),
    new Tuple<string, int>("Second", 2),
    new Tuple<string, int>("Third", 3)
};

// create the [UNION ALL]...SELECT clauses
var selectClauses = String.Join(
    " UNION ALL ", 
    data.Select(t => String.Format("SELECT '{0}', {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2)));

// build our entire SQL string
// this results in the string:
// "INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol) SELECT 'First', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Second', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'Third', 3"
var sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol) " + selectClauses;

// now execute this string against your database
```

If using this approach you should watch out for escaping quotes, SQL injection and the like.  This is just to get you started.

Comment: hi sir,
this post is good and helpful for me….but how can i insert N no’s of records when we are not Knowing exactly records

plz give me this kind of query solution to improve my query….

Comment: Not sure exactly of the best approach for your application, but the simplest method is to build the SQL string dynamically.  Create a string with the `INSERT INTO` clause, then iterate through the data you want to insert and append a `[UNION ALL...] SELECT` for each one.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: can you plz give me a simple query as an examples so i understand what you mean to say ? ? i'm using SQL server 2005...asp.net 08 with c#....so is it competible with my application requirements???

Comment: OK I added an example of how to dynamically create the SQL string in C#.

Comment: BTW - this assumes that the exam results are being entered through your ASP.NET application.  Is this the case?  It's not clear from your question where these results are coming from.  In fact, I'm re-reading your question and it's not very clear exactly what you want at all!

Comment: yes, inputs through application by admin or faculty. see, i am developing an web application as said (asp.net-c# and SQL 05)for student management system in which faculty fill marks dynamically at a time but there are no fix no of subjects for eg in semester 1 there are 5 subjects to fill marks in second semester 3 or it could be 7 subjects to fill obtained marks.... so i have only 1 **Exam_Result** table to add marks dynamically... now you got what i mean to say ??

Comment: So I think the first thing you need to do is select the subjects for the student / course / semester in question from the database, and display a UI listing these subjects next to a textbox so marks can be entered.  If your next question is then "how do I make that UI" then you should probably read some beginner's ASP.NET tutorials first.  Then if you still have problems, come back and show us what you've tried by posting your ASP.NET code.  Currently your question seems to be "how do I write my entire app" - it's a little too broad to be answered here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407809/how-can-i-insert-muliple-records-on-single-click-on-button-at-a-time-dynamically...see my problem by clicking this link

Comment: Mikey Cee - sir, i updated my problem as per your guidence. you can see it by clicking this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407809/how-can-i-insert-muliple-records-on-single-click-on-button-at-a-time-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a loop here is an example

> DECLARE @ID AS VARCHAR(25)
>
> SET @ID = '1,2,3,4,'
>
> SELECT @ID AS TOTAL_ID
>
> DECLARE  @DELIMITER CHAR(1)
>   SET @DELIMITER = ','
>
> DECLARE @CURRENTID AS INT
>
> WHILE(CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@ID,0) <> 0)
>
> BEGIN
>      SELECT @CURRENTID = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ID,1,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@ID,0 )-1 ))),
>
> ```
>      @ID = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ID,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@ID,0)+1,LEN(@ID))))
> ```
>
> SELECT @CURRENTID AS CURRENTID
>
> SELECT @ID AS REMAINING_ID
>
> END

As per your requirement i have done the loop for you

> DECLARE @IDSCORE AS VARCHAR(MAX)
>
> SET @IDSCORE = 'EM,23,;SM,25,;CL,30,;'
>
> DECLARE  @MAINDELIMITER CHAR(1)
>
> SET @MAINDELIMITER = ';'
>
> DECLARE  @DELIMITER CHAR(1)
>
> SET @DELIMITER = ','
>
> DECLARE @CURRENTIDSCORE VARCHAR(MAX)
>
> DECLARE @SUBJECTID AS VARCHAR(10)
>
> DECLARE @SCORE AS VARCHAR(10)
>
> IF(@IDSCORE IS NOT NULL)
>
> BEGIN
>
> WHILE(CHARINDEX(@MAINDELIMITER,@IDSCORE,0) <> 0)
>
> BEGIN
>
> ```
>   PRINT @IDSCORE
>
>   SELECT @CURRENTIDSCORE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@IDSCORE,1,CHARINDEX(@MAINDELIMITER,@IDSCORE,0 )-1 ))),
>       @IDSCORE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@IDSCORE,CHARINDEX(@MAINDELIMITER,@IDSCORE,0)+1,LEN(@IDSCORE))))   
>   SELECT @SUBJECTID = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CURRENTIDSCORE,1,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@CURRENTIDSCORE,0 )-1 ))),
>       @CURRENTIDSCORE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CURRENTIDSCORE,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@CURRENTIDSCORE,0)+1,LEN(@CURRENTIDSCORE))))
>   SELECT @SCORE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CURRENTIDSCORE,1,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@CURRENTIDSCORE,0 )-1 ))),
>       @CURRENTIDSCORE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CURRENTIDSCORE,CHARINDEX(@DELIMITER,@CURRENTIDSCORE,0)+1,LEN(@CURRENTIDSCORE))))
>
>   PRINT @CURRENTIDSCORE   
>
>   PRINT @SUBJECTID
>
>   PRINT @SCORE
> ```
>
> END
>
> END

Comment: looking nice, how can i implement in my case to insert into Exam_Result Table....as i explain above....can you help me??? thnx for guidence

Comment: @mack28 You have to append all the ids and marks in the id string as @ID=em,85,;sc,80,;

Comment: @mack28 I have modified the answer please check

Comment: Sir, thanks for instant helps...what you are doing is to define static scores and subjects but i want it for **N no of time** dynamically....subjects are not fix defined it might be modified as per semester changes...

Comment: @mack28 what you have to do is pass the id and score to the database in the above mentioned format to a variable in stored procedure