# insert muliple records on single click on button dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

i have 2 tables like....

> Here Admin Assigns Subjects to  faculties as per course and semester....

1] Assign_Subjects

```
Faculty_Id      varchar(20)     
Course_Id       varchar(20)     
Semester        varchar(20)     
Subject_Id      varchar(20)     
Subject_Name    varchar(50)     
Time            varchar(50)

INSERT INTO Assign_Subjects Values("F1","BCA",2,"DS","Data Structure","10-11")
INSERT INTO Assign_Subjects Values("F1","BCA",2,"C","C Programming","11-12")
INSERT INTO Assign_Subjects Values("F1","BCA",1,"QB","Q Basic","1-2")
INSERT INTO Assign_Subjects Values("F2","BCA",3,"SS","System Structure","10-11")
INSERT INTO Assign_Subjects Values("F2","BCA",3,"AC","Accountancy","11-12")
```

> Here Faculty do insert marks for students

2] Exam_Result

```
Result_Id           int(Auto no and PK)
Enroll_Number       varchar(50) Checked
Student_Name        varchar(100)    Checked
Course_Id           varchar(50) Checked
Semester            varchar(50) Checked
Subject_Id          varchar(50) Checked
Subject_Name        varchar(50) Checked
MarksObtained       numeric(18, 0)  Checked
Exam_Type           varchar(50) Checked
```

> now my question is how can i **insert all assigned subjects marks** to **Exam_Result** on **Single Button Click**

i.m giving general idea what i want is....

> In **FillResult.aspx**, here i want all subject names with textboxes (or any other possible way like gridview/dalalist etc) that are assigned by admin **and button(onClick event)** to fill the marks...

NOTE: Subjects appears as per assigning not fix number of subjects it may be 3 or 5 or more

so, How's it possible for me to do so.....??

> through gridview,edit templates or storesd procedures ????

all amswers are most welcome.....

Comment: Please be aware of [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Comment: @UweKeim hilarious, mack28 you should look up SQL Injection - use Stored Procedures with Parameterized commands..

Comment: Uwe Keim: nice... , Jeremy Thompson: can you give me a sample query or procedure so i can understand how could i implements it ??? ty

Answer (score 0):

**If you dont know the exact no of subjects to enter the marks - how are we supposed to generate a query to do it?**

Never the less to show you to protect against SQL Injection attacks you put you SQL in Stored Procs:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_GetAssignedSubjectsByFacultyIdAndSemester]
@FacultyID int,
@Semester nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT [Faculty], [Subjects],[CreatedBy],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedBy],[ModifiedDate]
 FROM [dbo].[tblNotSure]
WHERE [FacultyID] = @FacultyID
AND [Semester] = @Semester
AND [IsDeleted] = 0
END
```

Then in code we call the stored procedure, notice the Parameterised Commands, this prevents SQL Injection attacks. For example say we typed in the semester ddl/textbox (or using FireBug to edit the elements value) 1 UNION SELECT * FROM Master.Users - executing this ad-hoc SQL could return the list of SQL user accounts but passed though a parameterised command avoids the problem:

```
public static aClassCollection GetAssignedSubjectsByFacultyIdAndSemester(int facultyId, string semester)
{
var newClassCollection = new aClassCollection();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("pr_GetAssignedSubjectsByFacultyIdAndSemester", connection))
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultyId", facultyId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", semester);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    newClassCollection.Add(new Class(){vals = dr["vals"].ToString()});
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
             //at the very least log the error
            }
            finally
            {
             //This isn't needed as we're using the USING statement which is deterministic                    finalisation, but I put it here (in this answer) to explain the Using...
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return newClassCollection;
}
```

Comment: thanks jeremy Thompson, its only for retrieving the subjects as per faculty_id and semester....**but my question is for inserting marks into Exam_Result tableas per assigned subjects to a selected student's Enroll_Number**...i want to crate result or marksheet to do so....how could it possible through single click

Comment: what you'll probably need to do is INSERT INTO Exam_Results (SELECT * FROM aTempTable) or if that doesn't work create a Cursor and loop through the faculty/semester records inserting marks. Make it easier for us to answer, show us the SQL you have that works with multiple clicks that you want to work with a single click?

Comment: Jeremy Thompson - i have define here my question very needful and straight forward...plz see my this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10425871/1357042